# expressjs: serve static file ignoring cache buster

Tags: express, cdn

I've got a view helper that prepend md5 of `public/` files to act as a **cache buster**:

```html
<link href="http://localhost:3000/139cce29ff216955a42ae663b061730d/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Since md5 portion in the URL is just a "trick" for the browser, I'd like the static express middleware to serve the regular `public/index.css` file.

How can I write a such rule:

```js
//...

var static = express.static('public');

//...

app.get('/:md5([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})*', function (req, res, next) {

  var md5 = req.param('md5');
  var filepath = req.param(0);

  // --> NEED YOUR HELP HERE :) <--

  next();
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use Asset Rack or similar as suggested by @dankohn, I would do the following:

```
app.get('/:md5([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})*', removeHash, express.static('public'), restoreUrl);

function removeHash (req, res, next) {
  req._restoreUrl = req.url;
  req.url = '/' + req.url.split('/').splice(2).join('/');
  next();
}

function restoreUrl (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req._restoreUrl;
  next();
}
```

So to utilize express.static() I:

1. rewrite the url for every matching request
2. pass the request on to express.static(), which now sees a hash-free url
3. restore the url if the static handler didn't catch the request

Comment: Hey thanks for this one. What about just `res.redirect(filepath)`? I just tested this before your answer and it seems to work great.. Your thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't do that since it causes an extra request between clients and the server, for each file and client... I also wouldn't be 100% confident that _only_ assets will be matched, ever. That's why I restored req.url in the last middleware. If some new functionality one day uses hashes it shouldn't be broken because of a redirect. You can remove that function though if you're 100% confident nothing else will ever collide.

Answer (score 0):

Just install [Asset Rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack) and you can serve out both a public directory and a cache-buster versions of all of those files.